# Troubleshooting Help With IE8/Superfish Problem on SOME Computers Only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, superfish

Our website uses the superfish jQuery plug-in for our menus (http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/), and they work fine in Firefox, IE6, IE7, Safari, Chrome, etc. ... and even in MOST IE8 installations.  The problem is, in *some* IE8 installations, the menus don't work (they highlight on mouseover but don't drop-down the menu).

This has me baffled.  In addition to a couple customer complaints, I've got one (Windows XP) machine in-house that reproduces the issue.  However, I also have another Win XP/IE8 machine in-house which doesn't experience the problem.  I'm used to dealing with JS/CSS issues between different browsers, but this issue between two machines on the exact same OS and browser is a bit much.

Oh, and just to further obfuscate the matter, the machine that is reproducing the issue shows no errors, Javascript or otherwise (even when I go in to developer mode).  So ... does anyone have any suggestions on what could be going on?

As far as I know neither of my two "test" machines have any special plug-ins or anything which would cause the problem, they're identical in terms of everything that matters, and there's no JS error occurring that I can check the stacktrace of or anything.  But this isn't just some crazy problem that's unique to my test machine, because as I said some customers have reported it too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue wound up going away without us ever figuring out what caused it, so now even if we did want to figure it out we can't (as we can't replicate).  Therefore I can't really mark any of the above answers as correct, but since they exist I can't delete this issue either.  So, I guess the best I can do is file this answer, but it's a rather unsatisfying one; sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try setting the IE7 compatibility mode and see whether the problem persists?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

(into the head of the document, best would be directly after `<head>`)

If it works then, you'll definitely know that it is some IE8 specific rendering issue. My first bet would be that your menu uses CSS hacks to set certain IE specific settings, unaware that IE 8 (fortunately) behaves differently and more standards-compatibly than its predecessors. If that is the case, you would have to use an IE8 specific CSS hack (or, better, specific style sheet) to "re-fix" those settings.

But first, check whether this really is the problem using the compatibility view.

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately it didn't help :-(

Comment: Really odd. Are there any notable patterns with the machines it doesn't work with? 1. Screen resolution 2. Font size (dpi) 3. Javascript deactivated... If you can't find anything, you'll have to start debugging the JS in detail (e.g. adding alert()s to the various stages of highlighting and displaying the menu to see what gets executed and what doesn't) or change menus.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off compatibility view: Tools -> Compatibility View -> Uncheck.  I too struggled with this for the better part of an afternoon until I just tried this on a whim and it worked!

Comment: That didn't reproduce the issue either, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing Internet Explorers cache.   Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Browsing History section -> Delete ... -> Temporary Internet Files -> Delete.

For reasons unbeknownst to me, I've seen all IE versions start behaving strangely when the cache has been full or not cleared for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Windows 7 64bit Home premium. The laptop encountered an issue called SupperFish.
First I tried resetting home page to different URL’s. IE8 kept returning to SuperFish.com.
Look in Add and remove programs, was not there, Not in startup or MSCONFIG (startup). 
Third cleared Cookies then History. No help. Forth ran Microsoft Security Essentials, SpyBot S&D, Norton Constant Guard , Ad Aware. Problem is still there, Looked in C:\Program Files and found a folder called SuperFish, in that folder there was an Uninstall executable. I ran the Uninstall using a administrator account, and the problem is no longer showing up, after several hours of use.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it is a solution and that this is what you meant by not knowing how to fix it... but I cleared all my cache/history/cookies etc. from IE8 and if immediately worked (looking the same as other browsers).

maybe a fix for now but that worked...